# Disable HTML Buttons using Java Threads and jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, html, multithreading

I have a form with a submit button and jQuery, and I want to prevent the user from double clicking on the submit button by disabling the submit button using jQuery and java threads.

Any ideas???

Comment: Post your code that you have tried so far. That will give us some idea. To disable a button see [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/disable-enable-button-in-form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the form is submitted, you could just disable the submit button using jQuery:

```
$("form").on(
    "submit",
    function ()
    {
        // disables <input type="submit" /> and <button type="submit"></button>
        $(this).find("[type='submit']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
);
```

You probably have to adjust the selectors of the jQuery calls.

Answer (score 0):

abu taha9,

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="$(this).attr('disabled','disabled');"></button>
```

working example here
http://jsfiddle.net/9EecZ/